# Upgrade to 2.4.5-p1 app/code modules not recognized in setup:upgrade command

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

Upgrading from Magento 2.3.x to 2.4.5-p1, having sorted through the various PHP 8.1 issues, running `setup:upgrade` from the cli finishes, but the front end reports the standard `Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. The following modules are outdated:` error.

There are some really basic modules in the listing that have entries in the `setup_module` table, and no other changes have been made to the modules, and they are enabled as well.

For example:

`Hackathon_EAVCleaner schema: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1`

The module's `module.xml` has version `0.0.1` as expected, and the `setup_module` table also has `0.0.1` - but it looks like Magento is not recognizing the in-code version number to match to the `setup_module` version during the `setup:upgrade` command.

Is there something about the in-code module that needs to be updated in order for Magento to recognize the module is there?

Comment: What you get when you run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command ?

Comment: Completes as expected @SaurabhDwivedi (and includes the module in the example) - I also tried removing that module's row in setup_module, re-ran the setup:upgrade command - the module's row reappeared in the setup_module table, but still shows on the front end as missing.